# Selecting only one day bigger than given date in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL database which is loaded like:

[image]

Now I need to select only one level of dates that are greater than or equal given data. For example if the given is `11/13/2019` I need to have only all rows that have `11/14/2019`  like:

[image]

or if the given is `11/15/2019` returns only `11/16/2019` like

[image]

My dates are not always listed in sequence of real date format. As you can see there is gap between `11/14/2019` and `11/16/2019` and the `11/15/2019` is missing so I was not able to use the `BETWEEN` key in MySQL by adding a number to given on each select query.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select min(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.date > ?  -- the date you care about
               );
```